# How to show the login form from one component to another component?

Tags: angular, angular-services

I want to show the login form from login component if click on the `sign Up` menu from header component or some other component. How to do that?
I have the below the code.

**header.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: 'header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../app.component.css'],
})
```

**header.component.html**

```
<li  (click)="showmodel('login');" *ngIf="authenticationService.loginStatus==0"><span>Sign Up</li>                    
<li  (click)="logout();" *ngIf="authenticationService.loginStatus==1"><span>Logout</li>
```

**login.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../login.component.css'],
})
```

**login.component.html**

```
<div  data-backdrop="true" class="modal fade " tabindex="-1" [ngClass]="{'in': visibleAnimate}"  [ngStyle]="{'display': visibleAnimate ? 'block' : 'none', 'opacity': visibleAnimate ? 1 : 0}">                             
    <div class="modal-dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-content ">
            <div class="modal-header">Login form
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
    <app-header></app-header>
    <app-login></app-login>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>    
    <app-footer></app-footer>`,
    styleUrls: ['../app/app.component.css'],
})
```

Comment: why don't you create a seprate route for login form and call that root when needed

Comment: @vel a [shared service](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq) is the way to go

Comment: @RahulSingh, could you please explain how to do that?. Im new to angular.

Comment: @vel the shared service is a link in that comment please click and check the second question

Answer (score 0):

You should use a shared service with **`Subject`** variable and you can use that in other components,

```
export class AppMessageQueuService {
    authenticatedUserData: Subject<LoginInfo>;
    constructor() {
        this.authenticatedUserData = new Subject<LoginInfo>();
    }

}
```

where LoginInfo contains the information about the loggedin user

```
export class LoginInfo {
    username: string;
    role: string;
    token: string;
    isLoggedIn: boolean;
}
```

and then you can use this service in your header component,

```
 this._appMsgService.authenticatedUserData.asObservable().subscribe(value => 
 {
          this.isLoggedIn = value.isLoggedIn;
 });
```

Comment: could you please explain how to do that?

Comment: i getting this error `[ts] Cannot find name 'Subject'.`

Comment: import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

Comment: `Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AuthenticationService: (?).`

Comment: you need to inject the service